# WPF DataGrid displaying data based on ID

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Let's say I have the **Item** class, which has the **Category** property of **ObjectId** type.

```
class Item
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public string Name;
    public ObjectId Category;
}

class Category
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

I want to display all items in a **DataGrid** using **ViewModel.Items** and **ViewModel.Categories** collections. Something like this.

| Id | Name | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item.Id | Item.Name | Category.Name |

The question is, how do I get the **Name** value from the **Category** instance  with the matching Id of **Item.Category** property?

From what I've found, there are 3 ways: custom converter, generic converter using Reflection and wrapper objects.

**1. Custom converter**

This is the gold standard of WPF (which I don't like anyway). I could write a **CategoryIdToName** multi-value converter and simply supply **ViewModel.Categories** and **Item.Category** to get the name of the category.

The downside is I'll have to create a lot of those converters with boilerplate code.

**2. Generic converter**

This is similar to the previous, but using Reflection I could write ObjectIdToInstanceValue multi-value converter and supply 3 parameters: the collection, the ObjectId and the property name. This converter would try to find the item in the collection using the ObjectId and get the property value by the name.

The downside is Reflection is expensive (at least from what I've heard). But I'll only need one converter for all.

These two approaches don't appeal to me. Personally I dislike converters and I believe they hit performance of the application.

**3. Object wrapper**

I've never seen anyone implementing or even suggesting this approach. Basically, I could create a **DataGridItem** class, which could have the **Item** and **Category** properties. Then in ViewModel I could fill the collection and bind to the properties directly.

What's interesting again, I've never seen this way being used anywhere.

What is the best approach there?

Comment: Rather than _describing_ your code, _show_ your code. It's much easier to help fix your issue when we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: 'how do I get a Category instance to display some information about ithow do I get a Category instance to display some information about it' -- what is a "Category instance" and what is "it"?

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I need to display the name of the Category with the respective Id. Like we would write in code GetCategory(Item.Category).Name.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then, yes, like @mm8 says below, you should create a viewmodel to represent the rows in your grid, build it up with values, and return *that* to your view. MVVM (or to a lesser degree, MVC) pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display three columns in a `DataGrid`, you should create a view model class with a property for each of these columns. I guess this is what you refer to as an **object wrapper** in your question.

The view model of the `DataGrid` will be responsible for transforming your current data into an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a view model or wrapper type with the `Id`, `Name` and `Category` properties.

You will then bind the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to this `IEnumerable<T>` property and each column to a property of `T` as usual.

This is an MVVM solution in a nutshell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode (not really checked) to add on to my comment / @mm8's solution:

```
public class GridItem(){
  public string ItemName {get;set;}
  public string CategoryName {get;set;}
}
```

Then some method to query and build up your `GridItem` collection:

```
public IEnumerable<GridItem> GetGridItems(){
  return _repository.Items.Select(i => new GridItem{
    ItemName = i.Name,
    CategoryName = i.Category.Name
  })
}
```